# creating a array dynamic in heap using struct of Array

Tags: c++, arrays, array-merge

The below code is used to merge to arrays and the problem here is it is not creating an array dynamically in the heap so that the arr3 can be used for the merging of two arrays.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


struct Array{
    int a[10];
    int size;
    int length;
};

void Display(Array arr){
cout<<"Elements in array are ";
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        cout<<arr.a[i]<<" ";
    }
cout<<"\n\n\n";
}

Array* MergeArrays(Array *arr1,Array *arr2){

int i,j,k;

    i=j=k=0;

//here not creating an array in heap

  Array *arr3=new Array;
while(i<arr1->length && j<arr2->length){

    if(arr1->a[i]<arr2->a[j]){
        arr3->a[k++]=arr1->a[i];
    }else{
        arr3->a[k++]=arr2->a[j];
    }
}

    for(;i<arr1->length;i++){
        arr3->a[k++]=arr1->a[i++];
    }
    for(;i<arr2->length;j++){
        arr3->a[k++]=arr2->a[j++];
    }
    arr3->length=arr1->length+arr2->length;
    arr3->size=20;
    return arr3;
}

int main()
{

    Array arr1={{24,5,33,2,7,3},20,6};
    Array arr2={{22,6,8,12,15,9},20,6};
    Array *arr3;
    arr3=MergeArrays(&arr1,&arr2);
    Display(*arr3);
}
```

please help to create a array dynamically in heap by merging length of arr1 and arr2

to create a dynamic array struct is passed to arr3 pointer.

after the display function called to print the merging of arrays

Comment: The fact that you have `size` and `length` in your `Array` makes be think that you need a `std::vector<int>` instead.

Comment: You certainly do create that struct on the heap. I didn't go through all lines in your code to find potential errors, but: What error is it you are getting? What made you *think* you didn't create an array on the heap?

Comment: The problem is what you create the int a[10]; as fixed block of memory. It can't be resized. Use dynamically allocated memory and declare it as int* a; It is good for learning purposes. But practically you have to use STL, see the first comment.

Comment: I feel like this easily hops on the UB Express if the two arrays add up to a size greater than or equal to 10. The while loop check won't catch it, and the two for loops in there don't bother either. The answer lies with @armagedescu 's comment. And what's the difference between size and length? The passed size seems wrong no matter what. Writing your own vector (dynamic auto-expanding array) is a great practice exercise; it's also substantially more complicated than this.

Comment: Tamizh: Would [this](https://godbolt.org/z/3qehv8) be an option?

Comment: @TedLyngmo no it should be fully sorted

Comment: Tamizh: If the input Arrays are sorted, so will the result be - or what result did you get with my alternative?

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes your code is correct

Comment: **error is in my loop**
 ` Array *arr3=new Array;
while(i<arr1->length && j<arr2->length){

    if(arr1->a[i]<arr2->a[j]){
        arr3->a[k++]=arr1->a[i++];
    }else{
        arr3->a[k++]=arr2->a[j++];
    }
}

    for(;i<arr1->length;i++){
        arr3->a[k++]=arr1->a[i];
    }
    for(;i<arr2->length;j++){
        arr3->a[k++]=arr2->a[j];`**the rectified code**

Comment: @TedLyngmo i used basic pointers and arrays insted of STL

Comment: I noticed that you did - but why?

Comment: @TedLyngmo to understand the concepts .I'm still  a learner

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems.

1. The array in the struct is too small

   int a[10];

can only hold 10 elements but you have 2 * 6 = 12 elements that you want to save.

You probably intended to do:

```
int a[10];
```

2. The input isn't sorted.

It seems you want to merge the arrays in a sorted manner but that requires the input to be sorted from start.

3. Missing increment of index

   while(ilength && jlength){

   ```
    if(arr1->a[i]<arr2->a[j]){
        arr3->a[k++]=arr1->a[i];
    }else{
        arr3->a[k++]=arr2->a[j];
    }
   ```

   }

Where do you change `i` and `j` ?

You probably want

```
while(i<arr1->length && j<arr2->length){

    if(arr1->a[i]<arr2->a[j]){
        arr3->a[k++]=arr1->a[i++];
    }else{
        arr3->a[k++]=arr2->a[j++];
    }
}
```

**BUT ...**

If coding in C++ **do not** do something like the code above!

C++ has the `std::vector` that can do all this for you - and much more. For instance - unlike your `struct` - a `std::vector` (automatically) grows in size when needed. Use it together with functions from the "Algorithms library" and you'll be done in a few minutes.

Comment: i mentioned it in the comments see